# Number of currently visible elements in Grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin23

In my project, I use a grids with filtering and sorting via lazy-loading but also via in-memory filtering/sorting, depending on the expected number of elements in the database...
Of course, the user does not need to know the data retrieval mechanism, he just sees the table.
The user should be shown the number of elements that the grid currently contains (after filtering).
How can I retrive number of elements in both cases? Is there a simple and uniform way to get the number of elements currently displayed in Grid independent of how the data was retrieved and filtered/sorted, something like grid.getElementCount()?
I am using Vaadin 23.3.0

Comment: Hi! `grid.getDataCommunicator().getItemCount();` or `grid.getItems().size();` doesn't good for that?

Comment: Have you tried `grid.getItems().addItemCountChangeListener( ... )`?